# const io = require('socket.io') is expression is not callable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, use-effect

This is my index.js on the server side

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const router = require('./router');
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    }
});

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('We have a new connection');

    socket.on('join', () => {
        console.log(name, room); 
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User left!!');
    });
},)

app.use(router);

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Started at ${PORT}`));
```

It throws an error of this function not callable. Also,

This is my Chat.js (Chat Component) on the client-side.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import './Chat.css';

let socket;

const Chat = ( { location }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
    const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';

    socket = io.connect(ENDPOINT);

    useEffect(() => {
        const {name, room} = queryString.parse(location.search);

        setName(name);
        setRoom(room);
        
        socket.emit('join', { name, room });
    }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);

    return ( 
        <h1>Chat</h1>
    ) 
};
export default Chat;
```

The major problem I am facing here is that the useEffect is getting called multipile times even after I initilaized an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to define and connect to it socket-client on App.js instead of initializing it in Chat.js. In Chat.js, you just need to create its object. It should solve the issue of multiple useEffect calls.
************Edit**********
In App.js add these lines to intialize and connect

`import io from 'socket.io-client';`

`let socket;`

`const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';`

`socket = io.connect(ENDPOINT);`

And In Chat.js use below code at its respective place to emit events

`import io from 'socket.io-client';`

`let socket;`

`socket.emit('join', { name, room });`

Comment: Thanks for replying, the thing is that I am just a beginner so can you tell me how to connect it? I don't know if I am asking something very basic so apologies for that. Here's a link for my repo for better understanding: https://github.com/pranjalchaplot/missedmessage/